# Issue with reading and writing a name

Tags: javascript

I am just learning js and have the following issue that I cannot seem to resolve.  The object of the exercise is to read in the name when the button is clicked and then display a message that says "hello "

All of the functions are contained within the mainC div.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Sentence Diagrammer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to the Sentence Diagrammer!</h1>
    <h2>You can practice your diagramming skills here.</h2>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="mainL">
            <h1>Left Conatainer</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="mainC">
            <h1>This is the center</h1>
            <p>Please tell us your name</p>

            <p>I am <input id="theName" name="aName" type="text" /></p>
            <button onclick="validName()">Click</button>
            <p id="demo"></p>

            <input id="slide" type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" onchange="displayPrelimQ(this.value)" />
            <span id="slideValue">1</span>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function validName() {
                    var text1 = "hello";
                    var text2 = document.getElementById("theName").innerHTML;
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text1 + text2;

                }
            </script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function displayPrelimQ(val) {
                    document.getElementById("slideValue").innerHTML = val;

                }
            </script>
        </div>

        <div id="mainR">
            <h1>right container</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The issue I am having is that I cannot get the "Hello John" to print.  If I comment out text2, I am able to print out text1.

Comment: `document.getElementById("searchTxt").value;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the value of text input field using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript)

Comment: While testing, I also realized that after I ran the script once, I needed to refresh the page before attempting to push the button again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the value of an input is not available through `.innerHTML`, but through `.value`. The following works:

```
function validName() {
    var text1 = "hello";
    var text2 = document.getElementById("theName").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text1 + " " + text2;
}
```

Notice that an `<input />` is a self closed tag. (i.e. it has no corresponding `</input>`). Thus, it's inner HTML doesn't make much sense, since it is always empty.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Sentence Diagrammer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to the Sentence Diagrammer!</h1>
    <h2>You can practice your diagramming skills here.</h2>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="mainL">
            <h1>Left Conatainer</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="mainC">
            <h1>This is the center</h1>
            <p>Please tell us your name</p>

            <p>I am <input id="theName" name="aName" type="text" /></p>
            <button onclick="validName()">Click</button>
            <p id="demo"></p>

            <input id="slide" type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" onchange="displayPrelimQ(this.value)" />
            <span id="slideValue">1</span>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function validName() {
                    var text1 = "hello";
                    var text2 = document.getElementById("theName").value;
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text1 + " " + text2;

                }
            </script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function displayPrelimQ(val) {
                    document.getElementById("slideValue").innerHTML = val;

                }
            </script>
        </div>

        <div id="mainR">
            <h1>right container</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `#theName` is an *input* field, if you want to get the inputted *value*, you have to access its *value* property. For both `input`s and `textarea`s, to get the user input, use `.value` - for most other elements, to get their containing HTML, use `innerHTML` (or, if just text, `textContent`).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Sentence Diagrammer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to the Sentence Diagrammer!</h1>
    <h2>You can practice your diagramming skills here.</h2>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="mainL">
            <h1>Left Conatainer</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="mainC">
            <h1>This is the center</h1>
            <p>Please tell us your name</p>

            <p>I am <input id="theName" name="aName" type="text" /></p>
            <button onclick="validName()">Click</button>
            <p id="demo"></p>

            <input id="slide" type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" onchange="displayPrelimQ(this.value)" />
            <span id="slideValue">1</span>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function validName() {
                    var text1 = "hello";
                    var text2 = document.getElementById("theName").value;
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text1 + ' ' + text2;

                }
            </script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function displayPrelimQ(val) {
                    document.getElementById("slideValue").innerHTML = val;

                }
            </script>
        </div>

        <div id="mainR">
            <h1>right container</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing this line:

```
var text2 = document.getElementById("theName").innerHTML;
```

to this

```
var text2 = document.getElementById("theName").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is due to this line
`var text2 = document.getElementById("theName").innerHTML;`

You can have the desired outcome by modifying the above line to

`var text2 = document.getElementById("theName").value;`

What is the difference?
`innerHTML` reads the content between html tags. For [empty elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element) in HTML, there is no closing tag and hence, no content between tags.
`input` is an empty-element in HTML and hence, you need to read its `value`.